# how to install python module without pip after we download the module to local folder

Tags: python, module, pip, easy-install

we can download the module - `requests` , as the following

```
cd /home/module/
pip download requests
ls -l
certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl  chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl  idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl  requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  urllib3-1.25.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

now we can easily to install the module as

```
pip install *.whl
```

we can check it by

```
python -c "import requests"
```

now  - since on some Linux redhat machines we not have pip ( we cant install pip because security reasons )

*so we want to install the module without pip*

we try

```
 easy_install --install-dir=/home/module/*
```

but we get errors , maybe I not use it right ,

so can we get advice how to install the requests module without pip from local folder ?

Comment: `sudo easy_install requests` ??

Comment: this will install it from network , what we want is from local folder because on the machines we not have network

Comment: `sudo easy_install -b /path/ <pkg name>` ??

Comment: easy_install -b /home/module/*
Processing chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /home/module/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: I just said that you may have `pip` installed without knowing it, independent of what the security guy told you. Then of course, pure python wheels can be simply put into the site packages dir and Python will check them when importing modules. Run `python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"` and place the wheels into the dir. Of course, this is not the same as installing them - you won't get any executable scripts installed, only library modules. Also, shared libraries won't be importable, only pure python code.

Comment: maybe we can locate the pip temporary under /tmp/pip just to install the module and then to remove the pip under /tmp , is it possible?

Comment: You can download the `pip` wheel and run `python path/to/pip.whl/pip install path/to/requests.whl` for that matter.

Comment: is it posible to download 
pip 8.1.2  version by wget ?

Comment: You can select the release version PyPI. The page for 8.1.2 would be https://pypi.org/project/pip/8.1.2/#files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201046/discussion-between-jessica-and-hoefling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the module from source:

```
foo@bar:~/$ git clone https://github.com/psf/requests.git
foo@bar:~/$ cd requests
foo@bar:~/requests$ git checkout v2.22.0
foo@bar:~/requests$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: is it safe to install it from source ? second how to install it by  easy_install  ?

Comment: If you're pulling the source from the official repo and checking out a tagged release, I don't see any security issue there.

Comment: I get error - 
error: Setup script exited with error in urllib3 setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers.

Comment: what version of Python are you running?

Comment: python --version
Python 2.7.5

Comment: so any idea after I share the python version?

Comment: What version of setuptools? `python -c "import setuptools; print setuptools.version.__version__"`

Comment: python -c "import setuptools; print setuptools.version.__version__"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'

Comment: Not the latest. Can you try `easy_install --upgrade setuptools`?