# how to read any python module without its pip or conda installation

Tags: python, module, portability

I have no right to install the additional python modules using a pip or conda. The python installation already exists on the machine but it is limited to some standart libraries. Is there some way how to use a copied module from some directory. What I can do is to copy the files. The environment is linux.

What should be the way step by step to use for instance matplotlib.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install python module without pip after we download the module to local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58438767/how-to-install-python-module-without-pip-after-we-download-the-module-to-local-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't write in system's directories just install it in your user with --user parameters of pip. Keep in mind that some packages requires compilation and for these you will need a GCC and make usually and some devel libraries with the header files. To get that you will need to install the compiler and libraries, you may ask to your admin if this is the case.

Now if you can't use pip at all you can download the library source code and execute python setup.py install directly. But before doing that create a virtual enviroment and activate it, then run setup.py. This will make packages go to the virtual environment. Otherwise you may face permission denied errors if setup.py try to install files in the system's folders. Keep in mind that this has the same limitations as above, you may need a compiler and devel libs

Here is a mini how to

```
# create virtual environment
python3 -m venv ~/myvenv
source ~/myvenv/bin/activate 

# download the library
wget https://.../lib.zip
unzip lib.zip
cd lib

# install it
python setup.py install
```